# Authentication with user role

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am having trouble with customize the authentication system. I want to a user(from table user) to login with a column role where `user_id = 1` (admin). I already made a middleware called admin and my adminlogin function doesn't seem to work

```
public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request) {
    $admin = Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password],'user_id'==1);

    if ($admin) {
        Auth::login(Auth::user()->user_id == 1, true);
        return redirect('/backend/dashboard');
    }
    return view('backend.auth.backendlogin', [
        'message' => "Email or password is incorrect",
    ]);
}
```

Do I need to change the guard in Laravel authentication too ?

Comment: I hope [this post by Medium](https://medium.com/@ezp127/laravel-5-4-native-user-authentication-role-authorization-3dbae4049c8a) will help you out.

Comment: @o0o0keem can you show us the error?

Comment: @Miggy it always return Email or password is incorrect when i tried to login

Answer (score 0):

I think this will make your code work.

change:

```
$admin = Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password],'user_id'==1);
if ($admin) {
    Auth::login(Auth::user()->user_ ==1, true);
    return redirect('/backend/dashboard');
}
```

into:

```
$admin = Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password],true);

if ($admin) {
    if(Auth::user()->user_id === 1){
        return redirect()->intended('/backend/dashboard');
    }
}else{
    #rest of the code
}
```

Comment: lol i don't know why the snipper missing that but my code already had it i edited it. Sorry but that isnt the problem , if im missing the 1 it would show errors in laravel

Comment: did you test the code and does the error still persists?

Comment: yep the email and password still wrong even when i type it in correct and i checked the user_id is 1(from table user)

Comment: nvm mine doesnt work user with role_id=0 still can log in